# Scheme strings manipulation and defining procedure

Tags: string, casting, scheme, substring

I need help solving this problem as I have no idea how to solve this

Define a procedure pick that takes a non-empty string s and a non-negative integer i, and returns a substring of length one consisting of the character at index i in s. Assume that i is a legal index for the string s.

~ (pick "cat" 0)

"c"

~ (pick "cat" 1)

"a"

~ (pick "cat" 2)

"t"

Comment: This sounds to me like a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's simple using standard Scheme procedures:

```
(define (pick str idx)
  (string (string-ref str idx)))
```

Here's how it works: `string-ref` returns a character from the string at the given index, and the `string` procedure turns the character into a string of length one.

There's no real need to use the `substring` procedure (because we only need a single character), but that's a valid alternative, too.

Comment: how do you exactly use this to make the procedure? I do not understand

Comment: String-ref gets a character from the string at the given index, and the string procedure turns the character into a substring of length one

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [`substring`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=sub-string#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._substring%29%29).

```
> (substring "Scheme" 1 3)
"ch"
```

Here the letters of the word "Scheme" are numbered.

- The letter S has index 0.
- The letter c has index 1.
- The letter h has index 2.
- The letter e has index 3.
- The letter m has index 4.
- The letter e has index 5.

The expression `(substring "Scheme" 1 3)` makes a new string with
the letters numbered from 1 to 2. The index 3 is the first index 
not in the new string.

Since you want to pick out just one character, try this:

```
> (substring "Scheme" 1 2)
"c"
> (substring "Scheme" 2 3)
"h"
```

Now you can define your own function:

```
(define (pick a-string i)
    (substring a-string ??? ???))
```

What should the ??? be?